# Tanaka's Fuzzy House Price Problem

Tags: regression

I would like to understand and solve Tanaka's fuzzy house price problem (Table III). Unfortunately I couldn't able to build the problem structure and restrictions here (according to (19)). Anyone have face it before?

To double check, answers are below in Table-IV.

[image: Tanaka's House Price Problem]